# AWK to extract first two lines with same word in a column

Tags: ubuntu, awk, grep, tabs

I need to extract from a big multicolumn file (500mb to 1gb, \t separator) the first two lines containing a list of 100.000+ words appearing in a specific column.

Now I'm using a cycle like this one:

```sh
while read GREP
do
grep -m 2 "${GREP}" input.txt > output.txt ;
done < list_of_words.txt
```

but it takes too much time (i need to do this for many files), so i'm looking for alternatives.

a simple `fgrep -f -m2` don't work since -m applies to the whole output of merged hits.

I suppose awk may be a solution but could not find help online.

For example if the input file is:

```
Dog Bird House
Mouse Giraffe Cat
Mouse Rhino House
Lion Horse House
Dog Rat Cat
Dog Mice Cat
```

I'd like to have an output file like this (Order of lines isn't relevant):

```
Dog Bird House
Mouse Rhino House
Mouse Giraffe Cat
Dog Rat Cat
```

I'm now using a list of word like this one:

```
House
Cat
```

But if the is a method to just keep the first two lines where the same word on column three would be even better!
Note: words on column three will be unique and not appear in any of the other columns!

Comment: Provide a minified example with a sample file of a few rows, a list of 2-3 words, instead of 100K, and the output you want for that input. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please edit and add anything into the question, not in comments.

Comment: Thanks mate for the help

Comment: It doesn't matter because words on column three will be unique and will not appear on other columns

Comment: Do you care to preserve the order of `list_of_words.txt` into the output? In the example you want always first the 2 House lines or you are ok if the pairs of lines are in different order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=2;next}($3 in a)&&--a[$3]>=0' list input
```

Output:

```
Dog     Bird    House
Mouse   Giraffe Cat
Mouse   Rhino   House
Dog     Rat     Cat
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '           # yes awk yes, fields tab delimited
NR==FNR {                # process the first file, list of words
    a[$0]=2              # hash every word, set initial value to 2
    next                 # on to the next word
}                        # process second file below this point
($3 in a) && --a[$3]>=0  # if 3rd field word in a and seen max once, output
' list input             # mind the file order
```

Comment: OMG computing times went from more then 1h to less then 1 min

THANKS!